# Could not transfer artifact despite I see this jar inside my local repo

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I try to build my applivation and get followinf error message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project XXX: Could not resolve dependencies for project XXX:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.day.cq:cq-i18n:jar:5.4.4: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.day.cq:cq-i18n:jar:5.4.4: Could not transfer artifact com.day.cq:cq-i18n:pom:5.4.4 from/to repo1 (http://HOST.COM/content/groups/public/): Connection to http://HOST.COM refused: Connection refused: connect
```

But on filesystem I see that this jar exists inside following folder:

```
.m2\repository\com\day\cq\cq-i18n\5.4.4
```

[image]
How to fix this problem?

**update**

Tried to execute with -o option:

```
Failed to execute goal on project XXXs: Could not resolve dependencies for project XXX:bundle:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Cannot access adobe (http://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/) in offline mode and the artifact com.day.cq:cq-i18n:jar:5.4.4 has not been downloaded from it before.
```

Comment: Do you have in .m2\repository\com\day\cq\cq-i18n\5.4.4 the pom file also? Check if the jar has all it suppose to have, is not corrupted or anything like that.

Comment: http://joxi.ru/1bmooZOEULYpmy.jpg

Comment: i had similar case when my jar was corrupted, other thing is is it right path to your local repository? just doble check that

Comment: try to run with -o that will put maven in offline mode, maybe it will give at least some better insight of the problem

Comment: @Nadir topic updated

Comment: This time, try to run with -X option and compare output (pathes, ...) to what you really expect. It may also be a proxy issue if HOST.COM is an external url.

Comment: I don't see paths when I invoke with this option

Comment: Try removing the files with the .lastUpdated extension.  See here for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529218/maven-downloads-have-lastupdated-as-extension