# Error with maven when creating a bukkit plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I've been working on a minecraft plugin with bukkit for a number of months now. However, suddenly, my maven install stopped working. I'm quite new to maven (and programming) in general. I'm using eclipse and have never used maven from the command line. Here is the error:

```
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/5/maven-parent-5.pom
[WARNING] Failed to canonicalize path C:\Users\Minecraft\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\maven-parent\5\maven-parent-5.pom.lastUpdated: No more data is available
[WARNING] Failed to create parent directories for tracking file C:\Users\Minecraft\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\maven-parent\5\maven-parent-5.pom.lastUpdated
[WARNING] Failed to canonicalize path C:\Users\Minecraft\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\maven-parent\5\maven-parent-5.pom.lastUpdated: No more data is available
```

When I go to this local directory, there is no "5" directory and yet there is (I can't rename a file to 5 or anything like that). Network shared or something perhaps? But, I am able to delete the entire repository which is one thing I've tried.

What I've tried:

- I deleted my repository directory in its entirety and tried again. Same error.
- I've disk checked to make sure there were no issues.
- It doesn't seem to be a lastupdated issue as described here: [Maven downloads have .lastUpdated as extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529218/maven-downloads-have-lastupdated-as-extension)
- I tried using the wizard to create a new maven project. It warns me before the wizard completes that it won't compile. So, the wizard is not even creating a working project anymore.

Comment: How did you clear the maven repo cache?

Comment: @gonzo I deleted the entire repository at .m2/repository. Is there another cache other than that? I read this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408545/how-do-you-clear-apache-mavens-cache but it didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I helped Douglas resolve this problem. It turns out that this machine had some malware running on it. The system could not create the directory named "5" anywhere. And, as shown above, this particular project required the creation of a directory named 5. The infected file was called rlls.dll. Malwarebytes cleaned out the infected software and allowed us to remove the cache and rerun Maven without any problems. All solved now. Not actually a maven issue at all.