# Can't add dependency to Maven project

Tags: spring, maven

I'm making project in **Maven**. I added dependency to **pom.xml**, it downloaded dependency to maven repostitory

but I have getting following message:

> Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.0.0.M5

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
     <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>pl.tutorial</groupId>
     <artifactId>fiszki</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>           //here is showing mistake
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.M5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I checked and this dependency is downloaded in my Maven repository.

Comment: Did you add the proper spring.io repository to download milestone releases.

Comment: How I can check this ?

Comment: See http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/ select the version you want, the build tool you use and check what you need to do.

Comment: is there a "lastupdated" in your repo with the Spring JAR? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529218/maven-downloads-have-lastupdated-as-extension

Comment: Thanks, I read more and manual downloading helped. But how I can avoid those situations ?

Comment: Don't use milestone release and stick to stable releases...

Answer (score 0):

You can't add spring 5.0 dependencies, while in pom.xml maven schema location is pointing to 4.0.0.

Try to add Spring 4.0 dependencies. Any version you can use like :

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```