# Maven eclipse error: "Archive for required library cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I got the "Archive for required library cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file" error for my maven project I imported in Eclipse. I read some posts about this and suggested is to delete the faulty directory like in my case:
~.m2\repository\com\cogentex\rpw\2.2 and
~.m2\repository\com\cogentex\rpw-lkb\2.2
Then you should update the project via Eclipse: `Maven>Update project` and click `force update of snapshots/releases`.
I followed these steps and the directory looks like this now:
[image: screenshot]

So the correct .jar files are still missing and it also results in more erorrs now:
1: Missing artifact com.cogentex:rpw-lkb:jar:2.2
2: Missing artifact com.cogentex:rpw:jar:2.2
3: The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library '~.m2\repository\com\cogentex\rpw\2.2\rpw-2.2.jar'

Here is the snippet from the pom.xml which throws the first two errors:

> ```
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>com.cogentex</groupId>
>         <artifactId>rpw</artifactId>
>         <version>2.2</version>
>     </dependency>
>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>com.cogentex</groupId>
>         <artifactId>rpw-lkb</artifactId>
>         <version>2.2</version>
>     </dependency>
> ```

What do I have to do to make maven download the correct .jar files? I already tried running `maven clean`or `maven install` and restarting Eclipse.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13149707/6505250

Comment: I tried the answers there. I ran "mvn install -U", "mvn compile" in the directory of the project but I get the error "[...] Could not resolve dependencies for project edu.upc:bpmn2text_anselmo:jar:0.1.0: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.cogentex:rpw:jar:2.2, com.cogentex:rpw-lkb:jar:2.2, edu.upc:nlp4bpm_commons:jar:0.1.0, edu.upc:jfreeling:jar:4.1.0: Failure to find com.cogentex:rpw:jar:2.2 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced"

Answer (score 1):

What you see in the folder is some files that indicate the artifact was not found and when was the last time Maven checked.

Whatever `com.cogentex:rpw` is, it's [not in Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.cogentex) so Maven will not find it there. You need to tell Maven where to get it from by [providing the URL to a repository](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html) that contains it. If/when your POM has the repository, make sure

- you do have access to the reposiory from the environment you run your build in (check proxies, firewalls, ...)
- the GAV coordinates (groupId, artifactId, version) are correct and match the one in the repository.
- the artifact type in the repository is `jar`. If it is not, provide the correct type in the dependency
- the artifact is not [deployed to the repository with classifier](https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-deploy-plugin-2.6/examples/deploying-with-classifiers.html). If it is, provide the classifier in the dependency